# is hadoop necessary to run mahout-in-action examples?

Tags: hadoop, mahout

is hadoop necessary to run the Mahout In Action examples? i saw that there is a hadoop jar provided with mahout. i have been having problems with build-reuters.sh and was wondering if a seperate hadoop installation is necessary. thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Most of the book Mahout in Action concerns using Apache Mahout with Apache Hadoop. So yes, you will end up needing Hadoop. The book directs you to download and install Hadoop.

Hadoop itself is not provided with Mahout, no. However Mahout's build system references Hadoop, so it will automatically download dependencies like Hadoop. This is a different thing.

You have not said what your actual problem is with the script.

Comment: thanks very much. the script runs fine, after installing maven again.

however, there is another issue. i installed mahout and the hadoop plugin into eclipse. i can read and cluster the reuters data created by the script- very cool. however, when i create the document.seq file with a writer (my own example documents), running the same code gives nonsense: 0 belongs to cluster 1.0 for every document.

thanks again for your help. appreciated!